# Mirror macbook air screen to external display and then extend that display with another external display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have MBA mid 2013 and two 24 inch Dell external monitors. How to make mirror of laptop screen to one Dell display and then extend (or maybe I don't know which term should I use) with another Dell screen .

Like this one :

[image]

Comment: Does your VGA/HDMI/DVI extension cable have multiple output ports?

Comment: @HamidRohani No!

Answer (score 1):

You will either need an Apple TV and a thunderbolt to HDMI/DVI/VGA cable 
OR some thunderbolt dock capable of multiple outputs.

And then check out the final option at the bottom here [PH19039](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19039?locale=en_US)